# RxJS: distinct breaks after another subscribe

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm confused with `distinct` operator. As I understand it should produce only unique values from source stream. In my examples there two streams. The second one use `distinct` to prevent producing duplicated values, but after another subscription new (not unique) items produced again. I'm confused why this happens.

```js
const s1 = new Rx.Subject()
const s2 = s1.distinct().do(num => console.log(num))

a1 = s2.subscribe()
s1.next(1)
s1.next(1) // no produced because `distinct`
a2 = s2.subscribe()
s1.next(1) // produced, but why?
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the intended behavior, because if you create a new subscription for the subject the newly created subscription doesn't have an initial value. And if you emit the next item it get's emitted to the new subscription because `undefined` != `1`.

If you want to achieve the behavior that it only emits to all subscription if the value changed you have to use the `share` operator.

Here's an example:

```js
const s1 = new Rx.Subject()
const notShared = s1
  .distinct();
const shared = notShared
  .share();

notShared.subscribe(_ => console.log('subscription 1:', _));
s1.next(1)
s1.next(1)
notShared.subscribe(_ => console.log('subscription 2:', _));
s1.next(1)
s1.next(1)

console.log('_'.repeat(30));
shared.subscribe(_ => console.log('shared subscription 1:', _));
s1.next(1)
s1.next(1)
shared.subscribe(_ => console.log('shared subscription 2:', _));
s1.next(1)
s1.next(1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```